# How to convert list of strings to list of objects or list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, string, object, rbind

I have written a program in R that takes all of the .csv files in a folder and imports them as data frames with the naming convention "main1," "main2," "main3" and so on for each data frame.  The number of files in the folder may vary, so I was hoping the convention would make it easier to join the files later by being able to paste together the number of records.  I successfully coded a way to find the folder and identify all of the files, as well as the total number of files.

```
agencyloc <- dirname(file.choose())
setwd(agencyloc)
listagencyfiles <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
numagencies <- 1:length(listagencyfiles)
```

I then created the individual dataframes without issue.  I am not including this because it is long and does not relate to my problem.  The problem is when I try to rbind these dataframes into one large dataframe, it says "Input to rbindlist must be a list of data.tables."  Since there will be varying numbers of files, I can't just hard code this in, it has to be something similar to this.  I tried the following, but it creates a list of strings and not a list of objects:

```
allfiles <- paste0("main", 1:length(numagencies))
```

However, this outputs a list of strings that can't be used to bind the fiels.  Is there a way to change the data type from character strings to objects so that this will work when executed:

```
finaltable <- rbindlist(allfiles)
```

What I am looking for would almost be the opposite of as.character(objectname) if that makes any sense.  I need to go from character to object instead of object to character.

Comment: See `?mget` - like `rbindlist(mget(c("main1","main2")))` should work

Comment: @thelatemail thank you for the suggestion, I was able to make it work, but not in the way you suggested.  The issue with the way above is I don't know how many files there are in the folder to know how many "mainX" to include.  If you include too few, then data is missing, but if you include too many it throws an error and doesn't bind the list.  I was able to use your mget suggestion with 
allfiles <- mget(paste0("main", 1:length(numagencies)))
finaltable <- rbindlist(allfiles)

Comment: @thelatemail if you write it up as an answer below, I will mark it as correct since that was exactly what I was looking for.  I truly appreciate your help.